# Repairing animal damage in concrete driveway

Tags: concrete, driveway

My driveway has a few separate slabs (is this the right terminology?) and an animal has been digging in the gaps between two slabs. The gap is 1 - 1.5" wide. It looks like the rain is washing away the sand/dirt beneath because I can see open area.

What's my best course of action? I was planning on trying to fill the gaps with sand as best I could through the gap, and then seal the gap with something. Do I want to use something like a  caulk or something more like a tar? Links would be great!

Comment: Step 1, get rid of the animals so this doesn't occur again. I suggest a 12 ga.

Comment: I haven't actually seen the animal, but I will be dropping poison down there tonight.

Comment: Be really careful laying down open poison/traps, you don't want your or the neighbors' pets getting into it.

Comment: It turns out it was cicada killers digging between the cracks, and then when it rained the water washed away the loose dirt. Working on killing those suckers, and filling the cracks.

Answer (score 1):

I would fill gaps with [polymeric sand](http://www.quikrete.com/ProductLines/PowerLocJointingSand.asp?gclid=CILhsMaP_rgCFe1DMgodK38AnQ), then lightly water the joint lines (think 'mist' not spray).  The sand will 'set' like concrete, but with some flexibility, so it shouldn't freeze/frost heave.

Be sure to follow directions about packing joint and cleaning loose sand up before misting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty serious because the slabs can sink.  I have a small one that chipmunks had a small home - getting in via the expansion cracks.  It is down like 1/2 inch on one side where they were living.  I used rodent pellets in the hole and killed them all.  Then recovered with dirt and watered it down.  It has stopped the sinking but still got me a little.

Comment: So, any advice on filling the cracks?